# Why does those print same result?

Tags: c, string, pointers

Given a declaration:

```
char message[] = "hello, world"
```

Why does those print same results?

```
printf ( "%s", message );
printf ( "%s", &message[0] );
```

What I know is that, the `%s` only reads the first address of the character string. `char message[]` is also declared as a pointer to char strings (`char *message`), and `message` only reads as the first address of the character string.  However for `message[0]`, also is read as `*(message + 0)` and am I correct that it goes like this?

`&message[0]` = `&*(message + 0)` = `&*message` = `message`

Comment: Yes. In this context they are identical like you suspected.

Comment: To be exact, "%s" in itself doesn't read anything; it tells printf to expect an address of a character as the next argument, and to assume that there is indeed a sequence of characters at that memory location, ending with a character of the value 0 (i.e. the normal C string convention). The address is passed to printf, as haccks pointed out correctly, by "array decay" from char[] to char* which happened when the array `message` was used as an argument. `message` is a true array, not a pointer (try `sizeof(message)`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array names converted to pointer to first element when passed to a function as argument.
   `message` decayed to *pointer to first element*. It has type `char *` after decay.  `&message[0]` is the *address of first element*. It is also of type `char *`.

`&message[0]` is equivalent to

```
&(*(message + 0) ) =  &(*(message)) = &*(message) = message
```

`&` and `*` cancels the effect of each other.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, when an array name is passed as function argument, it decays to a pointer to its first element, so `message` and `&message[0]` have the same value in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions point to the first character - and the `printf` keeps going from there until it hits a `'\0'`

Answer (score 0):

A string is an array of characters terminated by a NULL character (\0).

So
 `message[] = "hello, world"`

So message or &message[0] indicates the starting address of the string "hello, world".
**So printf("%s", ), expects the starting address of the string . Since message or &message[0] gives starting address the results displayed will be same.**

Answer (score 0):

When you use printf with %s it writes chars from that point that you gave till \0(NULL). If we say "message" gives A03F address point to printf function, It starts to write char at A03F address and goes on to write till NULL character.
To answer your question yes they are same;
if message returns A03F address, &message[0] A03F address too. Because when you declare an array, that variable returns first address of that array- actually it is an pointer, too-